# Are there methodologies for the didactic study of history?

Tags: political-history, economy, social-history

When you ask someone what the purpose is of studying history, a standard response is that by studying history we come to understand its patterns which can inform us on our own circumstances and the choices we should take within them. For example this is epitomised in the famous phrase "Those who don't learn history are doomed to repeat it".

My question is whether there are established methadologies for converting historical knowledge into a 'pattern of history', or put differently if the purpose of studying history is didactic then what methodologies exist for interpreting historical fact so that one might learn from it?

I know that certain aspects of this question are heavily studied in reference to specific areas of history, i.e the analysis of historical economic trends being a basis for economic theory and similar attempts for the sake of sociology or geopolitics, but I am more concerned with attempts to provide fundamentals for historical interpretation generally.

If anyone knows about work being done in this area by historians, or has other insights I would be interested. Thanks.

Comment: Personally I study history so I can dunk on RETVRN types. So I can't help you there.

Comment: Historical materialism of Marx was one such attempt, although reducing everything to class struggle and economic relationships was overly simplistic. Scientifically we cannot extract much, since we are typically dealing with unique events.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Hi. Please let us know whether you had the chance to read Ibn Khaldun, Oswald Spengler, Arnold Toynbee, Peter Turchin or Jared Diamond. There are more authors, but probably you will feel confortable starting with any of those. Actually, cliodynamics is a topic related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but some might say that is what **sociology** is supposed to be for. Founding figures like Weber and Marx closely studied history and effectively gave birth to the field of sociology by attempting to theorize generalities from it. The mid-twentieth century sociologist C. Wright Mills famously defined [the sociological imagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociological_imagination) as the capacity to understand how history shapes one's biography.

However there is an inherent tension between the perspectives of historians and sociologists. I can't remember who first said that for the historian, "sociologists don't know anything" but for the sociologist, "historians don't know how to think". The historians job is to specify the facts, and the sociologists job is to theorize generalities that explain causal patterns in those facts.

Unfortunately they don't always read or talk to one another. Despite the influence of historically-minded thinkers like Weber and Matx and the popularity of Mills' conception of sociology as bridging biography with history (both are featured in most Intro to Sociology courses) the study of the past is somewhat marginalized in that field, with historical sociology considered a relatively minor subfield. For an exceptional look at how history can inform social theory the book [*Logics of History: Social Theory and Social Transformation* by William H. Sewell Jr.](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/L/bo3533904.html) might be a good place to start.